# Frontend can't connect to backend API in Docker

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, axios, discord.js, dockerfile

I have 3 docker containers all running through `docker-compose`. The backend and db containers talk to each other fine. But the frontend container can't reach the backend container. All 3 containers are on the same network. I can make Postman requests fine to the docker "backend" api through `https://localhost:5001/api/health` and it gives me the data I am expecting.

However, when I use the same link or even use the docker alias to connect my frontend to the backend, it gives me an "Connection Refused" error.

Here are my docker files.

**DOCKER-COMPOSE.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  dockerapi-dev:
    driver: bridge

services:
  backend:
    image: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5001:443"
    environment:
        DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "host=postgres_image;port=5432;database=db;username=user;password=password"
    networks:
    - dockerapi-dev

  postgres_image: 
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}postgres:latest
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - db_volume:/var/lib/postgres/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
    networks:
        - dockerapi-dev
  app:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./frontend/.docker/app/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./frontendt/.env
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
        - ./database:/app/database
        - ./logs/:/app/logs
        - ./assets:/app/assets
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dockerapi-dev
volumes:
  db_volume:
```

**BACKEND DOCKER FILE**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./Backend/Backend.csproj", "Backend/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Backend/Backend.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Backend"
RUN dotnet build "Backend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Backend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Backend.dll"]`


**FRONTEND DOCKER FILE**

`## build runner
FROM node:16.17-buster-slim as build-runner

WORKDIR /tmp/app

COPY ./frontend/package.json .
COPY ./frontend/package-lock.json .
COPY ./frontend/src ./src


RUN npm install

COPY ./frontend/.swcrc .
COPY ./frontend/tsconfig.json .


RUN npm run build

FROM node:16.17-buster-slim as prod-runner

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-runner /tmp/app/package.json /app/package.json
COPY --from=build-runner /tmp/app/package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

COPY --from=build-runner /tmp/app/build /app/build

RUN npm ci --omit=dev && npm cache clean --force 

CMD ["node", "build/main.js"]
```

In my front end code I make an axios request using the docker container name.

```
axios.get(`http://backend:5000/api/health`)
```

but I get the following error

```
AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.3:5000
```

However, if I make a Postman request from my machine using this URL it works as expected.

```
https://localhost:5001/api/health
```

I have tried many different things and am at a loss right now, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried local IP instead of localhost to fetch API in the frontend?
Try to use IP with API link instead of "localhost".

Comment: I have tried using the IP address instead of localhost and it does not connect.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: @Ccallaway I am facing a similar issue...  Were you able to fix yours ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a CORS issue. After deployed to docker, the front-end origin has changed. You can try to modify the back-end asp.netcore-api `program.cs` to allow all origins to see if it works.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
}));
```

```
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
...
```

If it is the problem, then you need try to only allow the correct orgins

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5500").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();  //for front-end host at 127.0.0.1:5500
}));
```